Action of general linear group on points of affine space
I'm not sure if my GAP code is correct. The exercise is to define action of general linear group on the points of 5-dimensional affine space over the smallest field.
gap> Afina:=AffineSpace(5,2);
AG(5, 2)
gap> T:=Points(Afina);
<points of AG(5, 2)>
gap> gl:=GeneralLinearGroup(5,2);
SL(5,2)
gap> f1:=ActionHomomorphism(gl,T,OnAffinePoints);
After that, a softwer GAP returns error when I write Image(f1), which is permutation representation.

I am not sure about how to do this using the finite geometry spaces, but on a more basic level the projective action on normed vectors does exactly what (I think) you want:
gap> T:=NormedRowVectors(GF(2)^5);;
gap> Length(T);
31
gap> f1:=ActionHomomorphism(GL(5,2),T,OnLines);
<action homomorphism>
gap> perm:=Image(f1);
Group([ (16,24)(17,25)(18,26)(19,27)(20,28)(21,29)(22,30)(23,31), (1,2,4,8,16)
  (3,6,12,24,17)(5,10,20,9,18)(7,14,28,25,19)(11,22,13,26,21)(15,30,29,27,23)
 ])

